# Pixel not the right size on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So my rectangle i want to draw on a canvas are, i think scaled to the size of the canvas. I i want them to be 8x8 they dont come out as 8x8.

Here's my code:

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('karte');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  Stuttgart = ctx.fillRect(10,10,8,8);
}
```

```css
.map {
 height: 799px;
 width: 591px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
 background-image: url('../img/Karte_Deutschland.svg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: center;

}

.map canvas {
  height: 799px;
  width: 591px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="karte">
</canvas>
```

Here's a screenshot how it looks like in the end: https://prnt.sc/r58bvl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now you set the canvas width and height on the screen different then the canvas actual width and height (which is 300/150 by default) it is why anything scaled for you. so :

**Eather** add the height and width to the canvas:

```
<canvas id="karte" height="799" width="591"><canvas>
```

**Or** add it manually in the js:

```
 canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
 canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight
```